# How to pass an object from page to modal component in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

i want to pass an object ( media: any={}; ) to a modal component to show media parameters like id etc.

This is what i have so far.

HTML PARENT COMPONENT

```
<ion-button fill="clear" (click)="modalPoints(media)">
```

TYPESCTIPT PARENT COMPONENT

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('modal') modal: GivePointsComponent;
    media: any = {};

async modalPoints(media) {
        this.media= media;
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: GivePointsComponent,
            breakpoints: [0, 0.4, 1],
            initialBreakpoint: 0.4,
            cssClass: 'custom-modal'
        });
        this.modal.media = this.media;
    }
```

TYPESCRIPT CHILD MODAL COMPONENT (GivePointsComponent.ts)

```
export class GivePointsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() media:any;
```

HTML MODAL COMPONENT (GivePointsComponent.html)

```
<app-modal-component #modal>
        <ion-label >{{media.msg_id}}<br>
          {{media.msg_id}}</ion-label>
</app-modal-component>
```

I should be getting the media.msg_id instead i am getting this as error on console;l

```
core.mjs:6469 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'media')
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'media')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass data tp the modal by using it as componentProps like this:

```
  async openModal(media: any)
  {
    let modal = await this.modalctrl.create({
      component: GivePointsComponent,
      componentProps: {media: media},
    });
    modal.present();
    modal.onDidDismiss().then(() => console.log('dismiss'));
  }
```

You get an error because you dont provide media -> media undefined error

Comment: now the modal dialog opens okj but media.msg_id is not shown and i am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'msg_id')

Comment: If you use the code in your question then 1. media is empty 2. if media is a consistent type you should make a type for it.

Comment: it returns null but it shouldn't be. I use the media parameters in other functions with click and they show the data. (click)="modalPoints(media)"

Comment: Do me a favor in the open modal function at the start do console.log(media) if its null there too, you passed null. If its not null then its a different problem.

Comment: yes it passes the parameters as wanted msg_id and all others

Comment: add console.log(media) to ngOninit in the modal it shoudnt be null there either in that case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252041/discussion-between-greencoms-and-simonioa).

Comment: @SimonIoa Cant edit my answer for some reason but just noticed that i fd up. Syntax for component props is  *componentProps:{media: media}* first media as identifier needs to be the same as import second is the actual prop. Hope this helps/fixes the Problem

Comment: OK that fixed it. So if i want to send another value is componentProps: {media: media. points:points},